# How to validate HTML response in post array in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, validation, tinymce-4

I am using [tinymce](https://www.tinymce.com/) for to add user cover letter related to the application.
This what my post array look like:

```
Array
(
[cover_letter] => <p>Test Cover Letter</p>
    <ol>
    <li>Need to save this data</li>
    </ol>
    <p><strong>Thanks</strong></p>
)
```

Simply I have used the `require` validation rule for this.

```
'candidate_cover_letter' => array(
    array(
            'field' => 'cover_letter',
            'label' => 'Cover Letter',
            'rules' => 'required'
    )
)
```

I get the validation error regarding this like **Cover Letter require**.

I have two main problem:

1. How to validate `HTML` post array data
2. Is this best practice to save data like this? if no then how should i save this data?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in Codeigniter if we want to do form validations we need to go like this :

```
    $config = array(
    array(
            'field' => 'username',
            'label' => 'Username',
            'rules' => 'required'
    ),
    array(
            'field' => 'password',
            'label' => 'Password',
            'rules' => 'required',
            'errors' => array(
                    'required' => 'You must provide a %s.',
            ),
    ) 
);

$this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
```

You can refer [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#setting-rules-using-an-array)

so, your code here should be like this in the controller:

```
$config =array(
    array(
            'field' => 'cover_letter',
            'label' => 'Cover Letter',
            'rules' => 'required'
    )
);
$this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
```

You can add extra fields in the $config like the example above.

Another thing that you asked, "How you should save the data ?"

I would suggest you to use a field in the database table with type "TEXT" and it should be okay for you.

Comment: I have taken care of this just i have not posted in the question.

Comment: So, is it working for you ? If there is any error then kindly paste the error here.

Answer (score 0):

After you hit submit you get redirected back to your controller somewhere. One way to utilize CI form validation is:

```
//look to see if you have post data
if($this->input->post('submit')){

    //points to applications/config/form_validation.php (look at next chucnk to set form_validation.php)
    if($this->_validate('cover_letter')){
      //rest of your post logic

     //get data to upload to database
     $data = [
         'cover_letter'=>$this->input->post('cover_letter'),
         'user_id'=>$this->input->post('user_id')

     ];
       //save data to database ..also this should be moved to a model
       $this->db->insert('name of table to insert into', $data);
    }
    //if you post doesnt not get validated you will fall here and if you have this chucnk of code in the same place were you have the logic to set up the cover letter you will see a pink message that says what ever error message you set up
}
```

Set up form validation.php

```
<?php

$config = [

    //set up cover letter validation
    //$this->_validate('cover_letter') maps to here and checks this array
    'cover_letter' => [
       [
        'field'=>'cover_letter',
        'label'=>'Cover Letter Required',//error message to return back to user
        'rules'=>'required'//field is required
      ],
      //example to add additional fields to check
      [
        'field'=>'observations',
        'label'=>'Observations',
        'rules'=>'required'
      ],

   ],
]
```

Comment: i think you didn't get the point i Codeigntier in not validation the HTML input. That's the porblem. the answer you suggest is what i have done already.